# geom_path function connects observations from different trials

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am plotting X and Z coordinates of a vehicle moving through space. To do this, I need to use the geom_path function to connect my observations in the order they appear. I want to plot individual trials and then facet_wrap by the condition (heading). Here is a subset of my data (character limits only allow me to include on condition here with a few trials):

```
df <- structure(list(rotatedX = c(0, -0.00233154842171665, -0.00476648757697326, 
-0.00698222415124088, -0.00930238211627776, -0.0116309926001574, 
-0.0139694475547738, -0.0162896055198142, -0.0186137320800091, 
-0.0209402812493384, -0.0232747676089956, -0.0255978635118695, 
-0.0279323498715226, -0.0302456013035568, -0.0325726658015963, 
-0.0349066368325391, -0.0372307633926346, -0.0395687030187473, 
-0.0418888609837841, -0.0442204094055008, -0.0465410826991485, 
-0.0488612406641777, -0.0511991802902862, -0.0535198535839339, 
-0.0558446495064834, -0.0581730527293198, -0.0604870743304282, 
-0.062774962558257, -0.06503460287124, -0.0672599121324647, -0.069459650928533, 
-0.0715866582195935, -0.0736586624394989, -0.0756585512895278, 
-0.0775778190238442, -0.0794297101525205, -0.0811681475201341, 
-0.0828057062744146, -0.0843557849592892, -0.0858089003988996, 
-0.08714783948779, -0.0883879080505865, -0.089519314843772, -0.0905497897964203, 
-0.0914860321805032, -0.0923156741093035, -0.0930339768187914, 
-0.0936645389707336, -0.0941899458466167, -0.0946163281626739, 
-0.0949450246437216, -0.095174957053083, -0.095309110908142, 
-0.0953510991568582, -0.0953072065492199, -0.0951878517596647, 
-0.0949976138708181, -0.0947503648235767, -0.0944547643977272, 
-0.094122872412392, -0.0937674236968396, -0.0933992933791348, 
-0.0930291017470821, -0.0926695836298239, -0.0923240858395225, 
-0.0919993608753416, -0.0916988620037289, -0.0914282102601053, 
-0.0911886911419573, -0.0909853627768583, -0.0908172420867048, 
-0.0906800467611938, -0.0905791429951607, -0.0905122622131119, 
-0.0904786285983957, -0.0904777800494025, -0.0905119319145222, 
-0.0905798995026895, -0.0906806521566798, -0.0908152205337254, 
-0.0909842739961582, -0.0911895125637726, -0.0914267660281197, 
-0.091700305404173, -0.0920018910819042, -0.0923365698930335, 
-0.0927055265287171, -0.0931097916459781, -0.0935384425375331, 
-0.0939940026190263, -0.0944806953261977, -0.0949918746141842, 
-0.095526302564721, -0.0960935099332089, -0.0966717045320525, 
-0.0972862326220224, -0.0979120560098166, -0.0985661748918884, 
-0.0992289592016179, -0.0999152470142581, -0.100621792324519, 
-0.101336280472676, -0.10208282544933, -0.102838343921114, -0.103619581244202, 
-0.104412161444553, -0.105222576533073, -0.106053041858167, -0.106889696774389, 
-0.107744340612622, -0.10860857408134, -0.109495588463413, -0.110394561857992, 
-0.111300702273821, -0.11221179436251, -0.113140668112176, -0.11408665416057, 
-0.115048206521654, -0.116008526612337, -0.116993327636079, -0.117987356995402, 
-0.118990614690342, -0.120009438698152, -0.121034553103638, -0.122071472487783, 
-0.123130142128169, -0.124199740123725, -0.125278051126371, -0.126366775155683, 
-0.127469365478104, -0.12857515422661, -0.12971042316045, -0.130840129933952, 
-0.131982826377182, -0.13315139570546, -0.134309557654843, -0.135486016593921, 
-0.136676134565173, -0.137875273610979, -0.139077249788002, -0.140290462388067, 
-0.141521456649007, -0.142748896836958, -0.14398484277086, -0.145226356512969, 
-0.146486167244664, -0.147740877917539, -0.14901285492278, -0.150287823093057, 
-0.151577996281356, -0.152879405892496, 0, -0.00231677973844604, 
-0.00464780214953004, -0.00697882456066773, -0.00930841813040999, 
-0.0116454731847705, -0.0139539296324, -0.0162849520434937, -0.0186092840213754, 
-0.0209350448406517, -0.0232682671445883, -0.0255859086891897, 
-0.0279312870344528, -0.0302572518699585, -0.0325647557566583, 
-0.0348988398667502, -0.0372281386654894, -0.0395503615053028, 
-0.0418764170955283, -0.0442081198033496, -0.0465468077153772, 
-0.0488670346785566, -0.0511866038518093, -0.0535090532145651, 
-0.05581710090197, -0.0581187754338571, -0.0604261420968108, 
-0.0626998068361008, -0.0649584346168483, -0.067186739450656, 
-0.0693840410408322, -0.0715786882367894, -0.073738725961668, 
-0.0758598451845214, -0.0779657909528441, -0.0800271936083574, 
-0.0820685467431585, -0.0840868794130421, -0.0860529127144334, 
-0.087991548271958, -0.0899096580283259, -0.0918064934388683, 
-0.0936556332828199, -0.095460706294462, -0.0972314646059951, 
-0.098977501346971, -0.100693554925504, -0.102382301514892, -0.104023806311464, 
-0.10563378584271, -0.107229203968101, -0.108783707714911, -0.110287227673178, 
-0.111788296525626, -0.113246545877644, -0.114648640604042, -0.116031592629419, 
-0.117371362135344, -0.118683960420401, -0.119939496532426, -0.121164051179775, 
-0.122335716916776, -0.123470867333092, -0.124571861324334, -0.125624909991496, 
-0.1266411260603, -0.127607446669695, -0.128538204519387, -0.12943217478416, 
-0.130274798241415, -0.131081949693654, -0.131840929298872, -0.132559266062032, 
-0.133238865104929, -0.133870110791321, -0.134460668622073, -0.13500681910831, 
-0.135516363519131, -0.135986897945508, -0.136409714298526, -0.136789574655145, 
-0.137130515782041, -0.137427140319151, -0.13768525365895, -0.137896193453919, 
-0.138068848574606, -0.138198321175889, -0.138286199101918, -0.138332118605949, 
-0.138335082113527, -0.138294998869956, -0.138214137016037, -0.138090319165741, 
-0.137924770144169, -0.137717126932332, -0.137467298775502, -0.137177327291569, 
-0.136844127546992, -0.136466247465885, -0.136052942576457, -0.135590284572923, 
-0.135089071086374, -0.134549075593771, -0.133956415530574, -0.133328420686075, 
-0.132664683027839, -0.131953407350357, -0.131192960795865, -0.130396634931666, 
-0.12955322482191, -0.128679197721987, -0.127758721659674, -0.126794745072471, 
-0.125791713487352, -0.124755523779219, -0.123680051822462, -0.122581310370967, 
-0.121470594387662, -0.120343684868566, -0.119197406125548, -0.118046999861017, 
-0.11689174003717, -0.115731082125483, -0.114573327637823, -0.113408587218191, 
-0.112254234941791, -0.11108863271596, -0.109927203752858, -0.108772306947933, 
-0.107611875559233, -0.106466322854149, -0.105333516460033, -0.104207332251159, 
-0.103102739665859, -0.102010620399649, -0.100944266019646, -0.0999141096825654, 
-0.0989045009256457, -0.0979151674846816, -0.0969652070471841, 
-0.0960577045465828, -0.0951738338319625, -0.0943267957156907, 
-0.0935067915965958, -0.0927224860054678, -0.0919763285926382, 
-0.0912621952323335, -0.0905797229055688, -0.0899332213710158, 
-0.089318653134258, -0.0887390573875137), rotatedZ = c(0, 0.133550336926087, 
0.27301861871855, 0.399857872027237, 0.532737098981801, 0.666165423233479, 
0.800081814287883, 0.932961041242448, 1.06608430965001, 1.1992685763436, 
1.332940925945, 1.46594216557397, 1.59961451517447, 1.73212768800072, 
1.8653729690836, 1.9989843042948, 2.13210757270236, 2.26596294936838, 
2.39884217632294, 2.53239251324903, 2.66533275459289, 2.79821198154654, 
2.93206735821165, 3.06500759955551, 3.19843595601556, 3.33229141320159, 
3.46602495433831, 3.59914852872627, 3.73208928540401, 3.86503033195706, 
3.99900891300618, 4.13182875209401, 4.26513720552682, 4.39826321164563, 
4.53132887975177, 4.6656765103083, 4.79856064903892, 4.93101850835603, 
5.06463646238677, 5.19874338505543, 5.33175293444416, 5.46525146857317, 
5.59807971404495, 5.73115288669983, 5.86526417360321, 5.99894922940472, 
6.13074364434089, 6.26479649352347, 6.39769087451499, 6.53083016658543, 
6.66482454584067, 6.79796549664205, 6.93196151852312, 7.06498201875592, 
7.19867445027452, 7.33065899422035, 7.46441368015039, 7.5977417162707, 
7.73076506694402, 7.86445993019346, 7.99784989864245, 8.1315450678723, 
8.26499617954405, 8.3972268262784, 8.52976244833595, 8.66272502618274, 
8.79629758688247, 8.92956480186368, 9.06380805382706, 9.19646451295451, 
9.32899863732297, 9.46293593160885, 9.59620171331771, 9.7289790578267, 
9.86230529027842, 9.99544818968603, 10.1288958872708, 10.2622822805901, 
10.3954853408662, 10.5286270968776, 10.6620126366752, 10.7960690770917, 
10.9287218161517, 11.0629607360897, 11.1955519132182, 11.3284479046281, 
11.4620148127593, 11.5963746663914, 11.7293308830855, 11.8618597413859, 
11.9953646366684, 12.128381175272, 12.2612144613524, 12.3961221078436, 
12.5280397432688, 12.6631300464275, 12.7957184858448, 12.9300762298296, 
13.0622982447224, 13.1954963610131, 13.3290604187047, 13.4608548658492, 
13.5950897919496, 13.7276771362824, 13.8617287132345, 13.9948649133025, 
14.1283060564836, 14.2625402739999, 14.3952489707364, 14.5285066842492, 
14.6610931106444, 14.7950217569827, 14.9290113210861, 15.0622685997859, 
15.1943054618618, 15.3273184736491, 15.4610025470963, 15.5951746390346, 
15.7273941416738, 15.8613829810898, 15.9948835926585, 16.1278959763836, 
16.2613963785979, 16.3942865402933, 16.5269935460906, 16.6609207430532, 
16.7947868290005, 16.9281036727131, 17.061298391022, 17.1945540109908, 
17.3268333041023, 17.4612480042221, 17.5936491328619, 17.7262332080454, 
17.8605255895113, 17.9926824029261, 18.1258763804425, 18.2595583925542, 
18.3931793097547, 18.5260069593717, 18.6592616452979, 18.7934924809356, 
18.9266250092488, 19.0596354282626, 19.1924017253015, 19.3262051864411, 
19.4587272970885, 19.592164543058, 19.7250525951044, 19.8586117249157, 
19.9925978910363, 0, 0.132733804487193, 0.266140264282087, 0.399546724076074, 
0.532953114790902, 0.666787481431959, 0.79903218044373, 0.932438640238625, 
1.06553933715381, 1.19864010314815, 1.33216884506782, 1.46496377910511, 
1.59928725121978, 1.73257129073068, 1.86481594368967, 1.99840581515944, 
2.13169001585504, 2.26460734714813, 2.39783030316261, 2.53142005949953, 
2.6654377687354, 2.79841609142027, 2.93151655807159, 3.06492260339154, 
3.19808360090602, 3.33136646607122, 3.46562701257858, 3.59884743569059, 
3.73225039547389, 3.86522427406625, 3.99758577492472, 4.13141325667543, 
4.26481144999681, 4.3974747071429, 4.53105354897282, 4.66383609481349, 
4.79728963806206, 4.93116968354634, 5.06370326709682, 5.19672422914285, 
5.3304161655704, 5.46496230384234, 5.59858981794749, 5.73142105908887, 
5.86394520182105, 5.99707902819994, 6.13051684442682, 6.26438095565283, 
6.39702102522722, 6.52972065855746, 6.66388569712119, 6.7973767908996, 
6.92927713480949, 7.0641095786649, 7.19826798562944, 7.33046886542848, 
7.46401275320432, 7.59712693807679, 7.73121721547077, 7.86396080066527, 
7.99768029417201, 8.12980894570376, 8.26279106223647, 8.39632131839175, 
8.52942164137979, 8.66294779883834, 8.79543305000442, 8.9287718122233, 
9.06314728993331, 9.19617635176137, 9.32999784114674, 9.46290068333801, 
9.5962291757887, 9.72998341060526, 9.86294116522149, 9.99571368907924, 
10.1282397144692, 10.2616802883565, 10.395729855099, 10.5285553571653, 
10.6614398703532, 10.7948722928999, 10.9279971334823, 11.0620364304575, 
11.1944851617753, 11.3283370635108, 11.461759262342, 11.594324219845, 
11.7275591155421, 11.8608530223618, 11.9942670237996, 12.1275568779753, 
12.2609057432718, 12.3941304152535, 12.527475227907, 12.6610012647286, 
12.7939755698106, 12.9271921365044, 13.0616283007564, 13.1936192369797, 
13.328051302535, 13.4615040979275, 13.5934889091321, 13.7282201289934, 
13.8617278828645, 13.9936456237114, 14.1267828239573, 14.2609561410092, 
14.3942724930495, 14.5285028870057, 14.6608991642159, 14.7937818988663, 
14.9270901456186, 15.0603965042064, 15.1935790839552, 15.3275539070485, 
15.4611610778429, 15.5938513514487, 15.7265408421582, 15.8600846268168, 
15.9932005967365, 16.1263774198879, 16.2599815972522, 16.3929139482587, 
16.5267011919021, 16.6592671800866, 16.7929932941807, 16.9264752584985, 
17.0594077476642, 17.1935006390545, 17.3265557557399, 17.4593671371256, 
17.5928508053969, 17.7259079023523, 17.8601873600314, 17.9937960966202, 
18.1261237376794, 18.2593686904022, 18.3937142052781, 18.5272063933113, 
18.6590512611521, 18.79230229284, 18.9251274900574, 19.0589924883007, 
19.1925537730136, 19.3254449353212, 19.4585819974097, 19.5922092932657, 
19.725349625101, 19.8587969402136, 19.9924292097689), pNum = c(11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L), EarlyResponses = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
), heading = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ppid_trialn = c("11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", "11_1_18", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", "11_2_20", 
"11_2_20"), FirstSteeringTime = c(0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 0.383333333333333, 
0.383333333333333, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 
0.35)), row.names = c(NA, -302L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've managed to get a plot that is almost right with the following code:

```
ggplot(df %>%
         dplyr::group_by(ppid_trialn), mapping = aes(x = rotatedX, y = rotatedZ, col = as.factor(heading))) +
  geom_path(alpha = 0.6) +
  facet_wrap(~ heading)
```

However despite grouping my dataframe by trial (ppid_trialn), the geom_path seems to connect all of the trials within the heading condition. This means I get straight lines that shoot back to zero (the same happens for trials in other conditions (1.5, 2 etc) when I facet_wrap.

[image]

Does anybody know how I would fix this? I have tried grouping my dataframe directly within the geom_path function but the same thing happens.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How did you try grouping the data.frame in `geom_path()`? Have you set `aes(group = .group)`?

Comment: @teunbrand I'm so silly of course! This has worked, thank you for commenting!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? This subset only has heading 1 so there is only a single facet

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = rotatedX, y = rotatedZ, col = as.factor(ppid_trialn))) +
  geom_path(alpha = 0.6) +
  facet_wrap(~ heading)
```

Comment: This does separate the trials, however ideally I want to set the colour as heading to match my other plots. The solutions posted in the comments does that if you're interested. Thankn you!